# AS3 youtube library event question

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, youtube

I am trying to build my youtube video search project in AS3.. and I found the following link...

http://blog.martinlegris.com/2008/02/20/youtube-data-api-as3-youtubeclient-functions-associated-events/

His library has

```
YouTubeClient.getStandardFeed(…)
Event: StandardVideoFeedEvent.STANDARD_VIDEO_DATA_RECEIVED
.feed: VideoFeed

YouTubeClient.getVideos(…)
Event: VideoFeedEvent.VIDEO_DATA_RECEIVED
.feed: VideoFeed
```

I am not sure the difference between these two...Could someone explain it for me? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this library but I took a stab at downloading it and look at the source code. Unfortunately the source code is not documented and it is from 2008!

At any rate, after looking around you can see that the creator gives you two examples that covers both events. One event listens for a custom search and the other one listens for a regular library that you would find in the homepage:

**Data API AS3 - First Tutorial**

http://blog.martinlegris.com/2008/02/19/youtube-data-api-as3-first-tutorial/

The example above covers a custom search and when you listen for the event you can scan through the results to display them to the user

**Youtube Data API in AS3 is ready!**

http://blog.martinlegris.com/2008/02/15/youtube-data-api-in-as3-is-ready/

In the example above you can see how the demo does a search for the TOP Videos in Youtube, once you get the results you can display them to the user.

So to recap. getStandardFeed should be used when you look for YouTube Top videos or such, and the getVideos method should be used when you are doing a custom search.

Answer (score 1):

Helmut Granda mentions that his links to the docs are very old, so for anyone interested, here is more recent documentation:

http://blog.martinlegris.com/2010/05/28/sample-code-using-the-youtube-as3-api-with-the-youtube-player-api/

Another thing to note if you use this API, is that as of Jan 2016 Google officially deprecated the searches and embedding from within Flash, and advocates developers search for and play videos using an API within in an i-Frame.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Quote:

> The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your
>   website and control the player using JavaScript. Unlike the Flash and
>   JavaScript player APIs, which both involve embedding a Flash object on
>   your web page, the IFrame API posts content to an  tag on your
>   page. This approach provides more flexibility than the previously
>   available APIs since it allows YouTube to serve an HTML5 player rather
>   than a Flash player for mobile devices that do not support Flash

However, if your Flash application would work better if within Flash than as an i-Frame, the player API is still actually functional past the cutoff date, and the searches can work within Flash if you do a URLRequest and parse the results in As3. My example follows:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
    import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class theaterYouTube3 extends MovieClip {
        public var pRoot:MovieClip = null;
        private var pSearchDataResultArray:Array = [];
        private var pSearchKey:String = "PutYourSearchKeyHere";
        private var pMaxSearchResults:int = 20;


        public function theaterYouTube3():void {
            traceOut("init");
            //date, rating, relevance, viewCount
            doYouTubeSearchSearch("trailers", "rating", pMaxSearchResults);
        }
        //
        private function doYouTubeSearchSearch(searchTerm:String, searchOrder:String, maxResults:int) {
            var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest();
            //request.url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?safeSearch=strict&part=snippet&q=" + searchTerm+ "&maxResults="+maxResults+"&key="+pSearchKey;
            request.url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?safeSearch=strict&type=video&part=snippet&q=" + searchTerm+ "&order=" + searchOrder+"&maxResults="+maxResults+"&key="+pSearchKey
            request.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json")];
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
            var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, searchDataRecieved);
            //loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, notAllowed);
            //loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, notFound);
            loader.load(request);
        }
        //
        private function searchDataRecieved(event:Event):void{
            trace("search data received");
            var vidsData:String = event.target.data;
            parseVideoSearchData(vidsData);
        }
        //
        private function parseVideoSearchData(vidsDataString:String){
            pSearchDataResultArray = [];
            var tempArray:Array = vidsDataString.split('"items":');
            if (tempArray.length ==0){
                parseVideoSearchDataError("no data");
            }
            vidsDataString = tempArray[1];
            vidsDataString=vidsDataString.split("{\n").join("");
            vidsDataString=vidsDataString.split("\n}").join("");
            vidsDataString=vidsDataString.split("\n}").join("");
            vidsDataString=vidsDataString.split("},\n").join("");
            vidsDataString=vidsDataString.split("}\n").join("");
            //trace(vidsDataString);
            tempArray = vidsDataString.split('"kind": "youtube#searchResult"');
            for (var i = 1; i< tempArray.length; i++){
                var resultString:String = tempArray[i];
                var vid_Id:String = extractVideoId(resultString);
                var vid_title:String = extractVideoTitle(resultString);
                var vid_thumb:String = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + vid_Id + "/mqdefault.jpg";
                var dataSet:Array = [vid_Id, vid_title, vid_thumb];
                pSearchDataResultArray.push(dataSet);
                traceOut("dataSet = \r" + dataSet + "\r");
            }
        }
        //
        private function extractVideoId(sourceString:String):String{
            //trace(sourceString);
            var parseArray1:Array = sourceString.split('"videoId":');
            var split1:String = parseArray1[1];
            var parseArray2:Array = split1.split('"');
            var itemValue:String = parseArray2[1];
            return (itemValue);
        }
        //
        private function extractVideoTitle(sourceString:String):String{
            var parseArray1:Array = sourceString.split('"title":');
            var split1:String = parseArray1[1];
            var parseArray2:Array = split1.split(",");
            var itemValue:String = parseArray2[0];
            return (itemValue);
        }
        //
        private function parseVideoSearchDataError (error:String):void{
            trace("parseVideoSearchDataError = " + error);
        }
        //
        private function traceOut(txt):void {
            trace("THEATER: " + txt);
            //traceLogin(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, one would call:

doYouTubeSearchSearch("trailers", "rating", pMaxSearchResults);

This would do a youtube video search for trailers based on rating.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I posted a link only to correct Helmut Granda's older links, not to provide an answer. I've updated my answer with quite a bit more information that I think would be useful to anyone trying to do this given even more recent changes to the API, and new restrictions introduced by Google which would make the accepted answer somewhat unusable.